# Which search to perform in InnoDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I've done some searching into fulltext searches for MySQL InnoDB and found a few on stack overflow, but they either don't provide an exact solution or they are a bit dated and I think it's time to rediscuss.

All of my tables are InnoDB and I'd prefer not to lock the entire database with MyISAM.  What are my options in regards to fulltext searching?  Are there any simple solutions?  I'd like to do the equivalant of `MATCH (content) AGAINST ("my search query" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalant of MATCH AGAINST in Innodb. Fulltext searching is one of pros of using MyIsam. So you should use standalone seaching server like Sphinx or Solr

Answer (score 1):

[InnoDB full-text search (FTS) is finally available in MySQL 5.6.4 release.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html#idp107829680)

These indexes are physically represented as entire InnoDB tables, which are acted upon by SQL keywords such as the FULLTEXT clause of the CREATE INDEX statement, the MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax in a SELECT statement, and the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement.
From [FULLTEXT Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index)